# What is Short if statements in java?

Tags: java

what is short if statement and no short if statement. I found this in Java Language Specification document. [It says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html) as follows

> "Statements are thus grammatically divided into two categories: those
>   that might end in an if statement that has no else clause (a "short if
>   statement") and those that definitely do not.
>
> Only statements that definitely do not end in a short if statement may
>   appear as an immediate substatement before the keyword else in an if
>   statement that does have an else clause.
>
> This simple rule prevents the "dangling else" problem. The execution
>   behavior of a statement with the "no short if" restriction is
>   identical to the execution behavior of the same kind of statement
>   without the "no short if" restriction; the distinction is drawn purely
>   to resolve the syntactic difficulty."

Can anyone please explain this ?

Comment: you really should add the preceding line: "The Java programming language, like C and C++ and many programming languages before them, arbitrarily decrees that an else clause belongs to the innermost if to which it might possibly belong. This rule is captured by the following grammar: "

Comment: @NathanHughes  Yes, the question reads a bit oddly without the context.  Thank you for providing it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the definition in the paragraph you referenced; a short if statement is an if statement that fits the patterns

```
if (condition) {
}

if (condition) {
} else if (condition) {
}
```

A non-short if statement doesn't fit that pattern, for example it might be any of the following

```
if (condition) {
} else {
}

if (condition) {
} else if (condition) {
} else {
}
```

and so on.

Basically, the "short if" statement is an if statement that is **known** to not have an else block.

Comment: You need to put a space in those `elseif`s.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thank you Paul, too many different languages, and just typing it in cold (not writing it in an IDE) have conspired to leave me space-less.  Editing now :)

Answer (score 2):

> Divided into two categories:
>
> those that might end in an if statement that has no else clause (a "short if statement")

```
if (condition) {

}
```

> and those that definitely do not

```
if (condition) {

} else { 

}
```

Leave out the curly brackets, you get one line if and else  statements.

```
if (condition) action();  // short-if 
// else doOther();  // optional
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other 2 answers, it's good to see what the problem is that this rule avoids.

For example, what does this print?

```
int a = 0; if (a == 1) if (a == 2) System.out.println("A"); else System.out.println("B");
```

It could be interpreted as

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 1)
    if (a == 2)
        System.out.println("A");
    else
        System.out.println("B");
```

(which would print nothing), or as

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 1)
    if (a == 2)
        System.out.println("A");
else
    System.out.println("B");
```

(which looks like it should print `"B"`).

However the rule excludes the second of these, because this `if (a == 1)` part does have an `else` clause, yet the statement `if (a == 2) System.out.println("A");` is a short if.

Therefore this prints nothing.

On the other hand, if the `if (a == 2)` was *not* a short if, it would look like this, and there would be no ambiguity to worry about.

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 1)
    if (a == 2)
        System.out.println("A");
    else
        System.out.println("C");
else
    System.out.print("B");
```

Comment: thanks for reply. In the code which u have given as                          int a = 0;
if (a == 1)
    if (a == 2)
        System.out.println("A");
else
    System.out.println("B");                                                                                                 But how do u say that statement if (a == 2) System.out.println("A"); is a short if coz when i run thses codes with a=1. I got the output as B. Then how do say that second if is a short-if.

Answer (score 1):

> Statements are thus grammatically divided into two categories: those that might end in an if statement that has no else clause (a "short if statement") and those that definitely do not.

It means **statements** are divided into **StatementNoShortIf** and **Statement**. Which **Statement** can appeared in a "short if statement" and **StatementNoShortIf** cannot.

A short if statement is a if statement without else clause.

```
IfThenStatement: // short if statement
    if ( Expression ) Statement

IfThenElseStatement: // not short if statement
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement

IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf: // not short if statement
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
```

> Only statements that definitely do not end in a short if statement may appear as an immediate substatement before the keyword else in an if statement that does have an else clause.

Only **StatementNoShortIf** can appear between the `if` and `else` in a non-short if statement.

And such **StatementNoShortIf** must be an **immediate substatement** of that `if else` statement.

> This simple rule prevents the "dangling else" problem. The execution behavior of a statement with the "no short if" restriction is identical to the execution behavior of the same kind of statement without the "no short if" restriction; the distinction is drawn purely to resolve the syntactic difficulty.

Therefore, consider the dangling else problem sample like this:

```
if (door.isOpen())
    if (resident.isVisible())
        resident.greet("Hello!");
else door.bell.ring();  // A "dangling else"
```

The `else` cannot be the part of the first `if`.

If so, according to the **immediate substatement** rule, line 2-3 need to be a **StatementNoShortIf** statement, but it is actually a **IfThenStatemtn** (short if statement) because **StatementNoShortIf** always needs an `else`. Therefore, the else must be a part of the second if, thus the dangling else problem is solved.